# JavaFX - How to dynamically bind TableView when Model contains a List

Tags: java, javafx

Let's assume we have the following scenario;

```
TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();

TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol,lastNameCol);

ObservableList<Person> data = // get data
table.getItems().addAll()
```

And a Model that looks like this;

```
class Person{

    private String firstName; // or SimpleStringProperty
    private String lastName;
    private List<Integer> favouriteNumbers; // or ListProperty etc

    public String getFirstName(){
          return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
          return lastName;
    }

    public List<Integer> getFavouriteNumbers(){
          return favouriteNumbers;
    }
}
```

A Person can have many favorite numbers that are defined at runtime. I need to dynamically create a table like this;

**First Name | Last Name | Favorite Number 1 | Favorite Number 2 | Favorite Number 3 | etc..**

I can create and add the columns dynamically by iterating over `getFavouriteNumbers()` list. By doing that, the number of columns that will be created will be the size of the biggest list. Rows with smaller lists will have their extra cells empty.

Problem is, I cannot figure out how to apply the binding for these columns.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you want to happen when someone has 5 favorite numbers but everyone else only has 1? You'll have 4 extra blank columns for each other person, yes? That is what you want?

Comment: @Zephyr Yes. The number of fields will be defined by the row with the max size of numbers list. Rows with smaller number list will have empty values for their extra cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split your issues in mutliple step :

1. Get the list of person to display in the table
2. Get the max number of favorite number to display
3. Create the needed columns and set custom cell value factory
4. Create the tableview

### Step by step code :

#### Step 1 : Get the list of person to display

I used a simpler version of the Person class to focus on your issue.

```
class Person {

    private final List<Integer> numbers;
    
    public Person( Integer... numbers){
        this.numbers = Arrays.asList(numbers);
    }
    
    public List<Integer> getNumbers(){
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

And we can write this methods in our application :

```
private ObservableList<Person> createItems() {
    ObservableList items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    items.add(new Person(0,1,2,3,4));
    items.add(new Person(2,3));
    return items;
}
```

This is just some kind of mock. You will certainly access to your model or persistence layer to have the list of Person.

#### Step 2: Get the number of column to display

```
private Integer getNumberOfFavoriteColumn(ObservableList<Person> persons){
    int maxNumberOfFavorite = 0;
    for(Person person : persons){
        maxNumberOfFavorite = Math.max(maxNumberOfFavorite, person.getNumbers().size());
    }
    return maxNumberOfFavorite;     
}
```

Pretty simple here. We loop and retreive the max size of the favorite numbers list.

#### Step 3: Create the needed columns and set custom cell value factory

We need to implement our own callback for the cell value factory. One way to do it is to create a class that implements Callback (Note that callback is a functional interface so you can use lambda if you prefer, or even anonymous class, or.. ).

```
public class PersonCallback implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String>, ObservableValue<String>> {

    private Function<Person,Object> extractor;

    public PersonCallback(Function<Person,Object> extractorFunction) {
        extractor = extractorFunction;
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String> cellData) {
        return new SimpleObjectProperty(extractor.apply(cellData.getValue()));
    }
}
```

And then we can create the columns :

```
   private List<TableColumn> createColumns(ObservableList<Person> persons) {
        List<TableColumn> columns = new ArrayList();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < getNumberOfFavoriteColumn(persons); i++) {
            final int index = i;
            TableColumn column = new TableColumn(String.format("Favorite Number %d", i + 1));
            column.setCellValueFactory(new PersonCallback((person) -> { return person.getNumbers().size() > index ? person.getNumbers().get(index) : "";}));
            columns.add(column);
        }

        return columns;
    }
```

I choose to return an empty String if the person has not this number but you can adapt regarding you needs.

#### Step 4: Create the table view

Now we have everything we need to create the tableview :

```
private TableView<Person> createTableView(){
    ObservableList<Person> persons = createItems();
    List<TableColumn> columns = createColumns(persons);
    
    TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView();
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(columns.toArray(new TableColumn[0]));
    tableView.setItems(persons);
    return tableView;
}
```

### Full code example

If we put everything together we obtains :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;


public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
        
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(createTableView());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    private TableView<Person> createTableView(){
        ObservableList<Person> persons = createItems();
        List<TableColumn> columns = createColumns(persons);
        
        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView();
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(columns.toArray(new TableColumn[0]));
        tableView.setItems(persons);
        return tableView;
    }

    private List<TableColumn> createColumns(ObservableList<Person> persons) {
        List<TableColumn> columns = new ArrayList();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < getNumberOfFavoriteColumn(persons); i++) {
            final int index = i;
            TableColumn column = new TableColumn(String.format("Favorite Number %d", i + 1));
            column.setCellValueFactory(new PersonCallback((person) -> { return person.getNumbers().size() > index ? person.getNumbers().get(index) : "";}));
            columns.add(column);
        }

        return columns;
    }

    
    private ObservableList<Person> createItems() {
        ObservableList items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        items.add(new Person(0,1,2,3,4));
        items.add(new Person(2,3));
        return items;
    }
    
    private Integer getNumberOfFavoriteColumn(ObservableList<Person> persons){
        int maxNumberOfFavorite = 0;
        for(Person person : persons){
            maxNumberOfFavorite = Math.max(maxNumberOfFavorite, person.getNumbers().size());
        }
        return maxNumberOfFavorite;     
    }
    
    private class PersonCallback implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String>, ObservableValue<String>> {
 
        private Function<Person,Object> extractor;

        public PersonCallback(Function<Person,Object> extractorFunction) {
            extractor = extractorFunction;
        }

        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person, String> cellData) {
            return new SimpleObjectProperty(extractor.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        }
    }
    
    private class Person {

        private final List<Integer> numbers;

        public Person( Integer... numbers){
            this.numbers = Arrays.asList(numbers);
        }

        public List<Integer> getNumbers(){
            return numbers;
        }
    }
}
```

This solution could certainly be grealty improved but I think it will help you to understand the concept and give you indication to solve your issue (and I only started JavaFX very soon)

Regards,
Quentin.

Edit: Add explanations & formating